# Refresh two amp-live-list with one button

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I have two amp-live-lists (which are related) One shows live events, and the other shows only highlighted events from the other list.

Right now, I need one button per live list, but I want to invoke the update function with the same button.

Highlight list:

```
<amp-live-list id="highlights-live-list" layout="container" data-poll-interval="15000" data-max-items-per-page="5" >
<button update class="ampstart-btn ml1 caps" on="tap:highlights-live-list.update">Hay actualizaciones nuevas</button>
<div items> 
        <!-- Items goes here -->
</div>
</amp-live-list>
```

Second list

```
<amp-live-list id="live-list" layout="container" data-poll-interval="15000" data-max-items-per-page="5" >
<button update class="ampstart-btn ml1 caps" on="tap:live-list.update">Hay actualizaciones nuevas</button>
<div items> 
        <!-- More items here-->
</div>
</amp-live-list>
```

I want to call to

```
tap:highlights-live-list.update
```

and

```
tap:live-list.update
```

In the same button

Answer (score 1):

For multiple actions for an event, you can use a comma:

```
on="tap:target1.actionA,target2.actionB"
```

See
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events